# UIAlertController like Contacts iOS 10 Contact app

Tags: iphone, ios10, contacts

I want to implement action sheet like the image. How that can be achieved?

[image]

Comment: Why you want to achieve this. it's already in. you just have to use it.

Comment: i want same in my application

Comment: But for what purpose.?

Comment: my app is similar to default iOS contact app

Comment: now i have done that

Comment: How you were able to achieve this? Please share the details

Comment: create using custom view. Used tableView to achieve this.

Comment: and if u will check default contact app , I think in that also tableview is used try to scroll that view it will scroll as if it is tableview with header

Comment: UITableView in actionsheet?

Comment: no use uitableview and present it as a action sheet

Comment: @Param: How to present uitableview as a actionsheet? can you please share some sample code...thanks in advance

Comment: Can't find the code. I did it almost 1.5 years back. But you need to use UITableView present it as action sheet and use table header for a title such as "Messages" as shown above.